# Show every element in list

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

Is there any operator or symbol, that would allow me to print all the elements in list (separated by comma)?

Because I have this (the list are actually keys from dictionary like dict.keys() ):

```
mylist = ['string1', 'string2', 'string3']
print mylist[:]

['string1', 'string2', 'string3']
```

I want the printed to stuff to exclude `[`,`]` and `'` without using `strip`. Is there any way?

P.S. Sorry to Mods if this is duplicate but I've tried searching for it but came with no results.

Comment: Then don't print it as a list, that's how Python formats it. Loop through and just print each with a space between them

Comment: That's what I was going to use but wondered if there's a simpler way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`print ", ".join([str(x) for x in mylist])`

[Here's](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.join) documentation on join.

If `mylist` already contains strings, it is enough to do

`print ", ".join(mylist)`

Comment: You can also do `",".join(str(x) for x in mylist)`. This avoid creating a list that is almost immediately deallocated.

Comment: I think this is more "pythonic" `', '.join(map(str, mylist))` ;-)

Comment: @pbacterio not sure why you think that: Guido is on record as disliking "functional"-style things like `map`, and [intended to remove it](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=98196) for Python 3 (he was dissuaded, but `reduce` *was* removed from the builtins at least).

Comment: @Bakiriu - using a generator here is also slower: `%timeit ','.join(str(x) for x in xrange(1000))` gives 271 uS; `%timeit ','.join([str(x) for x in range(1000)])` (python 2.6) gives 162 uS.

Comment: @pbacterio - Just so I'm not picking on anyone particular... the `map` solution also creates a temporary list, so is _usually_ slower than the equivalent generator solution. However, `str.join` is an exception that prefers lists, because it walks it twice, so in this case the `map` solution is also faster, around the same 162 uS.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
print ", ".join(mylist)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
import sys

for item in mylist:
    sys.stdout.write(item+", ")
```